# UIActivityIndicator not shown on top of webview

Tags: iphone, ios, interface-builder

I have a acitivity indicator and a webview. When I place the indicator on top of the webview, the acitivity indicator is not shown.

I have tried the option of placing webview and activity indicator separately. When I do the same, the indicator is shown but when I place it on top of the webview the indicator is not shown.

I have tried the option of setting the background to be black for the indictor and for the webview i have kept the same to be white.

Can anyone pls help me on the same.

Below is the code

```
@synthesize webView, acitivityIndicator;


- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Create a URL object
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];


    NSLog(@"URL address is: %@", urlAddress);

    //URL Request Object

    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    //Load the request in the UIWebView

    webView.delegate = self ;

    [[self view] addSubview:[self webView]];

    [[self webView] loadRequest:requestObj];
}

- (void) webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {

    NSLog(@"Web view did start loading");

    acitivityIndicator.hidden = NO;

    [acitivityIndicator startAnimating];    
}

- (void) webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {

    NSLog(@"Web view did finish loading") ;

    [acitivityIndicator stopAnimating];
}
```

Comment: Show your code that is creating and placing the views in question.  Without it, how can we know what you are doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using interface builder or are you creating your views programatically?

Comment: Hi, I am creating the views using interface builder.

Answer (score 3):

The `UIWebView` itself may have a white background, so that's why you don't see the `UIActivityIndicator`.

You should make sure that:

1. Your `UIActivityIndicatorView` is set
   to gray.
2. Your `UIActivityIndicatorView` is
   "below" the `UIWebView` on Interface
   Builder. The items at the bottom
   really are at the top.

This is an example:

[image: UIActivityIndicatorView over UIWebView]

Comment: Hi Pablasso, I am stil not able to get it to work. I have followed the step that you have mentioned but yet it doesnt work. Can you please provide me a example.. or can you check the code that I have written....

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code, if your Interface Builder already looks like the example, the only thing left to check is that the IBOutlets for "webView" and "acitivityIndicator" are set correctly. (please, fix the spelling :)